# Were there any hints to Bashir's unusual nature before its revelation?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

I can't be coy any further:

> Bashir was genetically engineered and enhanced.

I saw an interview with the actor (Alexander Siddig) who indicated that he'd NOT been told about the idea before the episode where it is revealed. But I imagine that the writers knew...that seems like a big thing to spring for a single episode of the week story.

Were there any hints to this aspect of his character in episodes which preceded the revelation?

Comment: I really want to say there were, but only in the few leading episodes.  I will need to go watch them again to have a real answer, unfortunately.

Comment: And here I thought it was going to be about the time he was a changeling.

Comment: @Zibbobz - it actually worked out quite nicely both times. This was something he was trying to hide well, so there wouldn't be any indicators. Same thing with the changeling bit - a good changeling wouldn't show any signs either.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No.  Because the writers didn't know.

To quote the background for DS9 5x16, *[Doctor Bashir, I Presume](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Doctor_Bashir,_I_Presume_%28episode%29)*, from Memory Alpha:

> The idea of making Bashir genetically engineered was a last minute decision. As Ira Steven Behr explains, "at the time we were working on "In Purgatory's Shadow" and "By Inferno's Light", we had no idea that Bashir was going to turn out to be genetically engineered. So even though it was the very next episode..." (Star Trek: Deep Space Nine Companion)

(The two episodes mentioned in the quote are 5x14 and 5x15, by the way)